# How to make an unimplementable interface?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to make a game communication protocol with a superinterface with 2 subinterfaces, but I want to make sure that no one will accidentally implement the superinterface. I can make a class abstract to prevent initialization, but allow extension. Is there a similar thing I can do to an interface to prevent implementation, but allow extension?

Comment: How would something like this be useful?

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694070/can-you-write-an-interface-that-can-not-be-implemented

Comment: Package-private superinterface and public child interfaces?

Comment: @Aaron Isn't this question about unimplementable interfaces as well?

Comment: @khelwood err, I guess I got confused.

Comment: @Michael II guess that would be the closest you can get in Java, but of course anyone who's determined enough could still just place the implementations in the same package. It would prevent accidential misuse, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such construct.

It is not possible to define an interface that can be extended but not implemented in Java.